# Modifying saved file without specific software

Tags: reverse-engineering

I have saved a file (with a certain extension) using a specific software. Is it possible to amend the saved file without using the software?

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific, what exactly do you want to edit? what kind of file is this? is it binary or text? is it saved locally or on the cloud?

Comment: the file is binary and it is saved locally. The file contains input information which the software analyse and provide an output. however, the input is done manualy through the GUI of the software. I'am trying to tweak the file to be able to include in the file the input without GUI to enhance the productivity.

Comment: You'll need to analyse the file, deconstruct the data. Then edit that data and make a new file based on the structure you found on the original. I think that would be your best bet.

Comment: Thanks  @TorbenVanAssche. Can you please advise how to deconstruct the Data.

Comment: First you will need to figure out how the binary file is encoded, so you know how to read it (either ascii or text). From there you can edit the data. Since you have not dropped the name of the software you are trying, I am going to assume you have a reason for that. You mainly need to set up a structure in your language of choice to manage the data coming in from the file and making it possible to edit it. There is usually a decryption key somewhere in the file, usually at the start